# Order Worksheets alphabetically EXCEL using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, xlsx, worksheet

I have many files with 7 worksheets each when they are named A, B, C ...G 
They are in the various orders. I am trying to concatenate the files together using the script below.

```
import pandas as pd

# filenames
excel_names = ["xlsx1.xlsx", "xlsx2.xlsx", "xlsx3.xlsx"]

# read them in
excels = [pd.ExcelFile(name) for name in excel_names]

# turn them into dataframes
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]

# delete the first row for all frames except the first
# i.e. remove the header row -- assumes it's the first
frames[1:] = [df[1:] for df in frames[1:]]

# concatenate them..
combined = pd.concat(frames)

# write it out
combined.to_excel("c.xlsx", header=False, index=False)
```

I need the uniform order of worksheets for each file to change the parameter [0] to [1] etc in the line.

```
frames = [x.parse(x.sheet_names[0], header=None,index_col=None) for x in excels]
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code you can write:

```
def get_sheet(x, i):
    return x.parse(x.sheet_names[i], header=None,index_col=None)


def get_sheets(i: int, excels):
    """Return a list of every *i*-th sheet from *excels*."""     
    return  [get_sheet(x, i) for x in excels]
```

That does not address the sheets by name, but a way to start, I think.